# Book series about a mage who goes to a magic school and is unknowingly descended from a strong mage family that can slow time

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a while back I was reading a book series about a mage.

Before someone becomes a mage they are at another level, I do not remember what it is called but it is wizard or something. They only are a mage if they are able to completely use all of their magic and it returns. Anyone who is not a mage is unable to ever use magic again if they use all of it. There are a few major families of mages and the main character is descended from one of them, which gives him the ability to slow down time. There are also the gods, who are afraid of mages. They fear being killed by them, so one of them attacked the mage.

I believe the mage also had a girlfriend of some sort. He was able to cool down a room or heat it up, as well as putting a protective layer over himself that physical objects would bounce off of. He was an extremely skilled fighter with a staff and he discovered his ability to slow down time while practicing with it.

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/70236) and see if you remember anything else, such as the years you read this in, the language, etc.

Comment: I read it in 2014-2016 not sure exactly when, it was in English. I also believe it was on amazon’s kindle unlimited.